# mikro-orm relation fields not being selected

Tags: mikro-orm

I'm trying to select nested relation fields and following the [docs](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/entity-manager/#fetching-partial-entities). However, the following query gives only id rating and review fields. What am I missing?

````
// in user entity
  @OneToMany(() => Review, (review) => review.by, { orphanRemoval: true })
  reviews = new Collection<Review>(this)

// in review entity
  @ManyToOne(() => User)
  by: User

...

      const reviews = await DI.reviewRepository.find(
        { service: id },
        {
          populate: {
            by: LoadStrategy.SELECT_IN,
          },
          fields: ["id", "rating", "review", { by: ["id", "firstName", "lastName"] }],
        },
      )
    ```

"@mikro-orm/core": "^4.5.4"
"@mikro-orm/sqlite": "^4.5.4"
````

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it working by including the relation entity in fields

```
...
fields: ["id", "rating", "review", "by", "by.firstName", "by.lastName"]
...
```